# a href moves with zoom in and out

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage written in dreamweaver.  I have my buttons as part of the background image and use a href to provide functionability to those buttons.  However when I zoom in or out with my browser those a tags move and the buttons in the background no longer align with teh a href tag.  Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you haven't enabled in your browser something like `Enable only text`.

Comment: You should leave the background image as a background image and put the button images as background images for the links. That will help with your zooming behavior and make your whole layout less picky about rendering differences in difference browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to slice those image buttons seperately, whether it's using Photoshop, GIMP or whatever you want and save them in your images folder. Then you can either use the `<img>` tag or have a `<div>` with a background using that image and set the "a href" on that.

So you could do either of these:

```
<a href="page"><img src="url" alt="some_text"/></a>
```

***OR***

**html:**

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

**css:**

```
div#image{
background-image:url('image.gif');
/* height and width of image */
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
}
```

---

To have them placed where you want on the page, you would have to place them in a div and then use css to add a margin or padding to be placed where you need it to be. So if you use the first option and you want it to be on the bottom right of a specific div, you would do this:

**html:**

```
<div id="specific_div">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#specific_div{
height: 400;
width: 400;
}

#image{
background-image:url('image.gif');
/* height and width of image */
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
}

#specific_div #image{
/* placement on page */
float:right;
margin-top: 150px;
}
```